# Header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, x-frame-options, shopware

I have tried to add `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` to my server. But no matter in what way I type it into my `.htaccess` file, it wont show up in the console of the browser (networktab - headers). I have a testserver where I tested the `.htaccess` file an there it works.

I have tried to add it like:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 
Header set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin" 
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 
Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
Header append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 
Header append X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 
Header always append X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
```

None of these entries worked. Its like they warent even there. Of course I tried one by one for those who think that my .htaccess looks like sample above :)

Other sections of my .htaccess show effekts so the apache can and is reading the file.

Why this option has no effekt?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Obviously my server runs FCGI so my .htaccess will be overwritten everytime. I had to add these header in my PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server seems not to allow those changes at `.htaccess` level, add the X-Frame options to your apache's vhost config for this domain or change the permission in the `location` section in the vhost config to allow proper X-Frame settings at your `.htaccess` project's level.